# To retrieve all values from firebase and put it into a TextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

[My Database Image from Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUWEX.png)

I want to retrieve both Dosa and Dosa2 and put it into a TextView.
Below is the code which I tried, but I am able to retrieve only Dosa2.

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("messages");

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Food food = postSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
                    foodnameTextView.setText(food.getFoodname()+"\n");
                }}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting textview every time in loop.Do like this:
Initialize the variable on top and append the text in loop than set it to textview

```
 mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("messages");

    // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
            String foodName="";
            mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Food food = postSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
                        foodName+=food.getFoodname()+"\n";

                    }
                    foodnameTextView.setText(foodName);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks alot, What a dumb mistake i made